# java.lang.Exception: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException when build Jenkins job which contains a Unit test for Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, junit

I have a Groovy class here:

```
class Excute {    
    static def excuteGroovyShell(String excute) {
        def result = new GroovyShell().evaluate excute;
    }
}
```

In my unit test, it's ok

```
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String excuteMath = "'java.lang.Math.abs(-6.0)'";
        String groovyScriptExcute = "com.example.Excute.excuteGroovyShell(" + excuteMath + ");";
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

        try {
            Object value = shell.evaluate(groovyScriptExcute);
            Object expected = (Object)(new Double(6.0));
            Assert.assertEquals(expected, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

It's ok when running the unit test. But when commit this source code to SVN. And build the Jenkins job, this problem will be happened:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: Script1

Stacktrace

java.lang.Exception: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: Script1
    at com.axonivy.person.groovy.GroovyTest.testCaseNormal(GroovyTest.java:45)
    at com.axonivy.person.groovy.GroovyTest$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.testCaseNormal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner$2.evaluate(CdiRunner.java:179)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:591)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:629)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:600)
    at com.axonivy.person.groovy.GroovyTest.testCaseNormal(GroovyTest.java:41)
    ... 31 more
```

Standard Error

Could anyone have any solution? Thanks !!! :)

Comment: Are you running it locally from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the wrong test. The stack trace says `GroovyTest.testCaseNormal` but your test code says the method is called `test()`.

Try to use your IDE to jump to the lines which are mentioned in the stack trace. That should help you locate it.

Comment: not sure this is an answer?  feels like more of a comment?